# How to set a data grid column to be a drop down when binding to a table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am able to create a data table and bind it to a datagridview. If possible I want something more sophisticated. I want to limit the first column to values 1 to 12 and the 2nd column to either AM or PM.

Thanks in advance.

```
        mDataTable = GetTable()

            DataGridView1.DataSource = mDataTable


Function GetTable() As DataTable
        ' Create new DataTable instance.
        Dim table As New DataTable

        ' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
        table.Columns.Add("Hour", GetType(Integer))
        table.Columns.Add("AM/PM", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Delete", GetType(Boolean))

        For i = 1 To mSchedules.Count
            table.Rows.Add(SetAMPMHour(mSchedules(i - 1).ScheduleINetHour), SetAMPM(mSchedules(i - 1).ScheduleINetHour), False)

        Next

        Return table
    End Function
```

Comment: [this](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) is a general demonstration of binding to a datagridview with a combobox column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `combobox column` is going to have fixed values, you can manually define those values either at design time or at runtime (althought both ways require you to set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `False` before you bind your data to your grid).

If you want to do it by code, try this:

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
Dim hoursCol, timeOfDayCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Dim deleteCol As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

For i As Integer = 1 To 12
    hoursCol.Items.Add(i)
Next
timeOfDayCol.Items.Add("AM")
timeOfDayCol.Items.Add("PM")

hoursCol.DataPropertyName = "Hour"
timeOfDayCol.DataPropertyName = "AM/PM"
deleteCol.DataPropertyName = "Delete"

DataGridView1.Columns.Add(hoursCol)
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(timeOfDayCol)
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(deleteCol)

mDataTable = GetTable()
DataGridView1.DataSource = mDataTable
```

If you want to do it in design time:

Create your `Combobox Column`...

[image: ComboBox Column]

...set `DataPropertyName` to the name of the column of the DataTable that will be binded to that GridView column, and in `Collection` define the values that will populate the `ComboBox`
[image: ComboBox Column Values]

Remember that, even if you define the values in design time, you have to programatically set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` before you set the data source. Also, if you create a ComboBox Column in design time, you'll have to fill it with `String` values.